# data.table as a data.table column

Tags: r, data.table

I want to have a column in a `data.table` which contains a `list` of `data.table`. I have a way to do it, which is to encapsulate each `data.table` themselves in a `list` before binding them togheter, but it bothers me. I would like the following to work, but it doesn't :

```
> x <- list(var1=data.table(a=seq(1:5), b=letters[1:5]), var2="foo")
> y <- list(var1=data.table(a=seq(6:10), b=letters[6:10]), var2="bar")
> z <- rbindlist(list(x, y))
Error in rbindlist(list(x, y)) : 
  Column 2 of item 1 is length 1, inconsistent with first column of that item which is
  length 2. rbind/rbindlist doesn't recycle as it already expects each item to be a uniform
  list, data.frame or data.table
```

If I encapsulate each `data.table` in a `list`, it works :

```
> x <- list(var1=list(data.table(a=seq(1:5), b=letters[1:5])), var2="foo")
> y <- list(var1=list(data.table(a=seq(6:10), b=letters[6:10])), var2="bar")
> (z <- rbindlist(list(x, y)))
           var1 var2
1: <data.table>  foo
2: <data.table>  bar
```

I don't like having to work this way because, when I select a single `data.table`, it is still encapsulated in a `list` as you can see below :

```
> z[1, var1]
[[1]]
   a b
1: 1 a
2: 2 b
3: 3 c
4: 4 d
5: 5 e
```

If I unlist it, I obtain 2 `list` instead of a `data.table` :

```
> unlist(z[1, var1], recursive=FALSE)
$a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$b
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

The only way to keep it a `data.table` is to select the first element of the `list` (which will always contains a single `data.table` anyways, I know) :

```
> z[1, var1][[1]]
   a b
1: 1 a
2: 2 b
3: 3 c
4: 4 d
5: 5 e
```

I solved my problem myself this way but, you know, I don't like this syntax. I would actually prefer not to encapsulate each `data.table`.

Am I missing something that would allow me to get it done without having to?

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't miss anything - you have to encapsulate it in a `list`. For tiny bit less typing, you can do `z[, var1[[1]]]` or `z$var1[[1]]`. There is no consistent way out of this, as only lists can store arbitrary non-conforming things, and `list(1, 2, 3)[1]` is not the same as `list(1, 2, 3)[[1]]`.

Comment: And if your `data.tables` *are* conforming - then do smth along these lines: `rbind(Reduce(cbind, x), Reduce(cbind, y))` and work with that data setup.

Comment: Thanks @eddi for your answer!